# How to change the default route in nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to switch a project of mine from Nuxt.js to Nuxt 3 and I have come across a problem.
I used to have the following option in my nuxt config config file:

```js
export default {
  router: {
    base: '/example-default-route/'
  },
}
```

Does anyone know how can I implement the same functionality of the above option, but in nuxt 3?

Answer (score 0):

```js
export default {
  app: {
    baseURL: '/example-default-route/'
  }
}
```

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config#baseurl